# App Development with Ruby on Rails

Tags: android, iphone, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to create a native app with ruby on rails on either the iphone or the android?

I know the programming language that is used for the iphone apps is objective c and the one mostly used for the android is java. But my friend told me he was working on making a phone app of his on the iphone and the android with Ruby on Rails. I thought Ruby on Rails was a web application frame and I have never heard anyone do this before(unless they are creating a web app). I thought maybe he was using some converter to translate the ruby of rails into objective c and or java. I tried asking him detail about it but he is only a business guy and it was recommended by someone use ruby on rails.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like your friend is probably making a web app that is designed to be used on an iOS or Android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make iOS applications using Ruby. Take a look at this [site](http://www.rubymotion.com/)